# How to fill a dataset with metadata even if the select query return no rows

Tags: c#, wpf, ado.net

I am using WPF data binding to a dataset to display the contents of a table.
The SELECT statement can return no records and the datatable will not get any metadata from this. Then the WPF `DataGrid` is minimised with no columns.
I know it is possible to specifically query the metadata of the table but I am checking if there is a shorthand method.

If the query is empty how do I still get the column information?

*People like to see code so here it is*
Currently I have:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedUserTable, Mode=TwoWay}"  Name="userTablesContentGrid"
    RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">            
</DataGrid>
```

In my ViewModel. DisplayUserTable is called to load the `SelectedUserTable` property

```
public void DisplayUserTable(string tableName)
{
    if (!UserTablesDataSet.Tables.Contains(tableName))
    {
        FillTable(tableName);
    }
    SelectedUserTable = UserTablesDataSet.Tables[tableName];
    InvokePropertyChanged("SelectedUserTable");
}

private void FillTable(string tableName)
{
    UserTablesDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", tableName), _conn);
    UserTablesDataAdapter.Fill(UserTablesDataSet, tableName);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue the DataAdapter.FillSchema command.

```
UserTablesDataAdapter.FillSchema(UserTablesDataSet, SchemaType.Mapped);
```

Comment: Does the FillSchema method replace the Fill method?

Comment: Nope. That just fills the schema. Generally speaking you want to issue the FillSchema method before Fill every time when you need what you're after.

Comment: Thanks but I have tried this with no change: UserTablesDataAdapter.FillSchema(UserTablesDataSet, SchemaType.Mapped, tableName);
            UserTablesDataAdapter.Fill(UserTablesDataSet, tableName);

Comment: Please reference this MSDN example - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135707.aspx - filling the data set without the table name is what you need to do - it will only fill the table that exists in the select statement.

Comment: Thanks Mike. There was a change in my dataset afterall but it didnt show in the datagrid.