# DataAdapater : StackOverFlow Exception with empty row

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I am trying to fill a `Dataset` using `SqlDataAdapter`. For this I wrote a simple function as below

```
public static DataTable GetData(string Query, SqlParameter[] parameters=null)
{
    using (ReliableSqlConnection con = new ReliableSqlConnection(DBUtility.ConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = Query;

            if (parameters != null)
            {
                foreach (SqlParameter p in parameters)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
                }
            }
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            //da.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source);
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (StackOverflowException ex)
        {
            return null;
        }catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is latest modified version, when I call this function, I get

`Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.`  exception, and my IIS crash and close the Application Pool on live server. (in Visual Studio, it just stop the debugger ). Oh, this happen when my Query returns a Empty recordset, i.e. my query is valid but return zero rows. If data is present it works just fine.

I search and as this question ([How to fill a dataset with metadata even if the select query return no rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668013/how-to-fill-a-dataset-with-metadata-even-if-the-select-query-return-no-rows)) suggest to use FillSchema, I try but no change found. I had "table" name define for Fill, which I remove and still no change. Even though the piece of code is in `Try catch`, it still crashing the server (I do not see typical ASP.NET error page, but a `503 Service not found` kind of error when this happens.

I am using .NET Framework 4.5.1/4.6.1 (yup try to run on 2 version).

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Data.dll`

I just realise it is doesn't fail for my other query with empty record, then I realise that for query it fails has a Column as "varchar(max)" as datatype, testing if it is true, but I think that is cause of error.

Failing Query is: `select TitleName, [Message] from tblVerbiage where SaleId=@SaleID`

I try to cast to varchar(200), and it still gives error. So, my thought is maybe my Table is somewhat corrupted? I did a `DBCC checktable` which return success. I notice that this error is coming of this table only.

---

#### Solved

It turns out there was logical issue in code that iterate the query, and hence some memory leak might occur that cause the error.

Comment: There is no way to catch stack overflow - it simply kills the process. So whatever you see is expected.

Comment: Could you please post stack (partial) when exception caught by VS?

Comment: What is reliableSQLConnection class? can you show us the code in that class

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the Stack Trace is empty.

Comment: @Viru, reliableSQLconnection is Microsoft's Azure class, the came in Nuget package from them, it just implement retry over SQLConnection.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov can you see edit3.

Comment: Please provide the failing query. I think it's not because of varchar(max), but because of where/join conditions.

Comment: @unconnected added. :) it doesn't have any thing other than varchar(50) and varchar(max) field.

Comment: I'd suggest to replace DataSet with DataTable for debuging.  Three last lines like this: DataTable dt=new DataTable(); da.Fill(dt); return dt;

Comment: @unconnected I already did that :), and did again as you said, it change error from System.data.dll to system.transactions.dll (`An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Transactions.dll`)

Comment: And the final debug option. Try tio replace the ReliableSqlConnection with classic SqlConnection.

Comment: @unconnected nope no change.

Comment: The issue becomes really interesting. Are you running your queries over production Azure SQL?

Comment: yes, it is on s2 plan I guess. but the problem is there when I run it on Sql express. I really start to doubt if it is my table, but what not sure.

Comment: @unconnected well it seems there is logical error in my code and it is calling that function in loop, and though the function is discrete as you can see,it somehow generate the exception as it gets called too many times. damn, this code is 6 yrs old.  Thanks for help though.